# Are JPA annotation @index necessary for existing index?

Tags: jpa, indexing

I wonder what is the purpose for the annotation, I am developing app in Spring for the first time, based on existing database, do I need to add @index annotation for indexes that are already in the database?
The API didn't say much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html) says:

> Used in schema generation to specify creation of an index.

So, it's only useful if you use JPA to generate your database schema from the annotated entities, in order to generate a schema. If you generate your schema in another way and the index exists, adding an Index annotatiuon is useless.